# PHP/JSON parsing

Tags: php, ios, json

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [faq_id] => 14
        [faq_faqcat_id] => 3
        [faq_order] => 8
        [faq_subject] => 800018
        [faq_content] => 800019
        [faq_datecreated] => 1213382678
        [faq_dateupdated] => 1215547984
        [faq_views] => 22
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [faq_id] => 15
        [faq_faqcat_id] => 3
        [faq_order] => 9
        [faq_subject] => 800020
        [faq_content] => 800021
        [faq_datecreated] => 1213382698
        [faq_dateupdated] => 1215547986
        [faq_views] => 13
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [faq_id] => 16
        [faq_faqcat_id] => 3
        [faq_order] => 10
        [faq_subject] => 800022
        [faq_content] => 800023
        [faq_datecreated] => 1213382711
        [faq_dateupdated] => 1215547988
        [faq_views] => 15
    )
)
```

The above data is output of a PHP script. I have to convert this to a JSON object and show on an iPhone. can anyone please tell how?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) and [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) functions

For the parsing part on iOS you can use the native [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about iOS side, but from PHP it's pretty simple

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```